# How to list libraries of site and subsites of office 365 (c#)

Tags: development, office-365, library, web

How can I get a tree view that contains all the sites and subsites, and the list of libraries for each one of those?

(I use C# , Office 365, Windows Forms)

I tried this and it's ok but i just have subsites of level 1 , I didn't find a solution to do it recursively ( I want to have all subsites in a treeview when I load my form )

```
    string p_path = "https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/";
    string mainpath = https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/;
    try
    {
        clientContext = new ClientContext(p_path);
        SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in ("your password")) passWord.AppendChar(c);
        clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("your login", passWord);
        Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
        clientContext.Load(oWebsite, website => website.Webs, website => website.Title);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        int i = 1;
        foreach (Web orWebsite in oWebsite.Webs)
        {

            string newpath = mainpath + orWebsite.ServerRelativeUrl;

            treeView1.Nodes.Add(orWebsite.Title);
            treeView1.Nodes[i].ForeColor = Color.Navy;
            clientContext.Load(orWebsite.Lists);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (List list in orWebsite.Lists)
            {
                if (list.BaseType == BaseType.DocumentLibrary)

                    treeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(list.Title);
            }
            i++;

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to make it recursive (includes only the web title portion, you'll have to add the list functionality):

```
ClientContext ctx = null;
try
{
    ctx = new ClientContext( siteUrl )
    {
        Credentials = _credentials
    };

    var oWeb = ctx.Web;
    ctx.Load( oWeb, web => web.Title, web => web.Webs );
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    treeView1.Nodes.Add( oWeb.Title );
    treeView1.Nodes[0].ForeColor = Color.Navy;

    if ( oWeb.Webs.Count >= 1 ) GetSubWebs( ctx, oWeb, 1 );

} finally { if ( ctx != null ) ctx.Dispose(); }
```

The recursive function (this can probably done better, and in a way where it isn't called a single time outside the function):

```
private void GetSubWebs( ClientContext ctx, Web web, Int32 node )
{
    ctx.Load(
            web,
            oWeb =>
                oWeb.Webs.Include(
                    subweb => subweb.Title,
                    subweb => subweb.ServerRelativeUrl,
                    subweb => subweb.Webs ) );
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach ( var subWeb in web.Webs )
    {
        var url = _serverUrl + subWeb.ServerRelativeUrl;
        treeView1.Nodes.Add( subWeb.Title );
        treeView1.Nodes[node].ForeColor = Color.Navy;
        node++;
        if ( subWeb.Webs.Count >= 1 ) GetSubWebs( ctx, subWeb, node );
    }
}
```

I did this rather rushed, so like I mentioned before, it can probably be improved upon.  I hope this can at least get you started.

Comment: this code don't show the libraries of each site and subsite !